# How to assign the output of the system() to a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Hi I'm quite new to C++ and programming. If this is a dumb question I hope you forgive me.
Let's say that I ran "whoami" command in cmd, I get something like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>whoami
laptop-i4c2v3qs\username
```

if I write a code like this in C++,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

int main(){
   system("whoami");
   return 0;
}
```

How do I assign the output of the whoami command executed by system() to a variable? In this case it's "laptop-i4c2v3qs\username".

Comment: You can't. On unixish systems you'd use `popen()`, but I don't know what options exist on Windows.

Comment: Using the `system` function? You can't. Or at least not easily. Considering you're on Windows you should learn the [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function (which admittedly isn't easy to use either, but it's more flexible and powerful than `system`, and is what `system` uses).

Comment: Never ever use `system`. Your particular problem can be solved in a C++-standard manner with the `popen` function instead. Bear in mind that  `popen` is a C function and requires you to use `stdio` facilities inherited from C, rather than native C++ facilities.

Comment: @n.m. Actually `popen` is a POSIX function, not a standard C (or C++) function. On the other hand, Windows have the compatible [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, it is not C standard, my bad.